# Which Xamarin.forms Permissions are required to see other apps or apk installed on the device?

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, permissions

When dealing with permission on Android, we have to ask the user permission like, phone, sms, storage, etc. Some of which are dangerous and the user needs to explicitly grant such permissions.

Which permission do I need to ask for to let my app know if there is another specific app is on his or her phone.

For example Facebook can figure out that Messenger is not installed on my phone so and suggests me to install it.

Comment: We can iterate over the [installed apps](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getInstalledApplications(int)) and then check if desired app's package info is available or not in this list.

Comment: So we don't need to let the user know we are looking in that list? Cause that is what I thought we needed to ask the user to know that we are looking for a certain app. 
So make a new code method that looks at the list and validates if present or not.

Comment: Yeah, it's not mandatory. Though, you can let user know you're accessing this info. Based on user acceptance, you can implement the flow.